# DNN login module gone. Unable to log into DNN 6 site

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I was trying to change my default login page on my DNN 6 site. I added a page called "login" to the root of my site.

After doing so, it appears that the default DNN login page has been removed, and now no pages exist on my site that have the login module on it.

When I click on login skin tokens, it just produces a popup for the login page I created, which does not have the login module on it.

I also tried the ?ctl=login, and this produces the exact same result as the skin token.

Help? Ahh!

Alex

Comment: Got my hosting provider to reset it for me. Apparently they have some sort of one click host admin login button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex,

Create a new aspx page called AutoHost.aspx or any name difficult to judget. Change inheritance of the page from `System.Web.UI.Page` to `DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault` add following line to page load event:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthenticationCookie(HostUser,true);
Response.Redirect("/Default.aspx");
```

Upload this page to root of the site and navigate to it.

This will login you as host user and you can do corrections you want.